# What does a TortoiseSVN cleanup actually do?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

What does a TortoiseSVN cleanup actually do?

I have not found a pattern, but I frequently get asked to do a "cleanup" while trying to commit code.

If TortoiseSVN knows when it's dirty, why doesn't it run a cleanup itself?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Edit:** I think it's not automatic as it needs to abort operations and unlock the working copy in /path.

Subversion book:

> Recursively clean up the working copy,
>   removing locks and resuming unfinished
>   operations. If you ever get a working
>   copy locked error, run this command to
>   remove stale locks and get your
>   working copy into a usable state
>   again. ” Note that in this context
>   lock refers to local filesystem
>   locking, not repository locking.

It's basically a way of trying to recover any errors that occur with SVN.

Documentation on cleanup:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html

> "If a Subversion command cannot
>   complete successfully, perhaps due to
>   server problems, your working copy can
>   be left in an inconsistent state. In
>   that case you need to use TortoiseSVN
>   → Cleanup on the folder. It is a good
>   idea to do this at the top level of
>   the working copy.
>
> Cleanup has another useful side
>   effect. If a file date changes but its
>   content doesn't, Subversion cannot
>   tell whether it has really changed
>   except by doing a byte-by-byte
>   comparison with the pristine copy. If
>   you have a lot of files in this state
>   it makes acquiring status very slow,
>   which will make many dialogs slow to
>   respond. Executing a Cleanup on your
>   working copy will repair these
>   “broken” timestamps and restore status
>   checks to full speed."

Comment: I don't get it every single time, but I see it pretty often.

Comment: I know this doesnt help but i havent seen the message at all and ive been using it for about a year now. Is it when you commit or just randomly?

Comment: Sorry re-read your post, you do you commit over wireless or are you prone to network issues in general? maybe that could have something to do with it. Is it being stored within your local network or are you storing the commit's remotely?

Comment: NO we don't have any network issues.  It's on the local network.  As I said, it's not every time, it just seems to happen randomly.  I'm guessing that I am doing something that is causing this.  Moving files, deleting files or something...

Comment: The clean up also seems to remove or compress svn files that are no longer needed. On our systems I have, for some projects, seen the hidden .svn folder reduced to less than 20% its former size after doing a cleanup.

Answer (score 20):

It puts duct tape over bugs and a dumb architecture in [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) which allow the working copy to be corrupt.

It's not automatic for dumb architecture reasons and because it takes FOREVER. Of course, when SVN got popular its architecture was miles ahead of [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System).

Answer (score 7):

It looks for inconsistencies. From [the docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html):

> If a Subversion command cannot
>   complete successfully, perhaps due to
>   server problems, your working copy can
>   be left in an inconsistent state. In
>   that case you need to use TortoiseSVN
>   → Cleanup  on the folder. It is a good
>   idea to do this at the top level of
>   the working copy.
>
> Cleanup has another useful side
>   effect. If a file date changes but its
>   content doesn't, Subversion cannot
>   tell whether it has really changed
>   except by doing a byte-by-byte
>   comparison with the pristine copy. If
>   you have a lot of files in this state
>   it makes acquiring status very slow,
>   which will make many dialogs slow to
>   respond. Executing a Cleanup on your
>   working copy will repair these
>   “broken” timestamps and restore status
>   checks to full speed.