# Exclamation mark in <SolutionName.suo> file does not go away even after SVN commit

Tags: tortoisesvn

After I add and commit changes from my VS2008 solution folder, I have noticed that the the exclamation mark on all files and folders changes to a checkmark after the commit is completed to SVN repo, except for the  file which is in the same folder as the  folder. Even after I hit Refresh or perform SVN update and then Refresh, the exclamation mark stays. Is the problem between the chair and the keyboard or a known SVN issue. Please note that I am using Tortoise SVN 1.6.9 on Windows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should notbe adding *.suo files to source control. It is bad practise, especially if you have multiple users working on the same project or solution. You should add all *.suo files to the SVN ignore list.

That said, the problem you describe is fairly common with Tortoise SVN and SVN in general, in my experience. Sometimes Tortoise SVN / SVN can get a bit confused, the .svn meta-data folders can get out of sync with the server copy, or even corrupted. To solve this problem, your working copy needs to be 'Cleaned up'.

Try the following:

Select the folder of your working copy in Windows Explorer, then

Right Click - Tortoise SVN - Clean Up.

If this doesn't work immediately, try multiple combinations of updating your working copy, then cleaning it, then updating again. This usually fixes the problem.

Read [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539772/what-does-a-tortoisesvn-actually-cleanup-do)  for more.

The problem is also quite often with Windows/Windows Explorer itself. Refreshing of the SVN status icons doesn't always happen immediately. I believe it is a problem/limitation of the combination of Windows Explorer and the Tortoise SVN shell plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Please do this

Directory ->Right Click->Check For Modifications -> On Modifications(select all)->Right click -> "Commit"-> In the bottom pane click "Refresh". Now it should have removed that warning sign.